# why typescript array returned appears as '[object Object]' instead of Iterable for ngFor?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a simple array of strings(Iteratable) in typescript and use Angular ngFor to display all of them on my page. I tried several ways of creating an array but none of them return iteratable back.

the last effort I did looks like this.

```
  vehicles: String[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.vehicles.push('vehicle 1');
    this.vehicles.push('vehicle 2');
    this.vehicles.push('vehicle 3');
    this.vehicles.push('vehicle 4');
    this.vehicles.push('vehicle 5');
    console.log(this.vehicles);
  }
```

I also tried

```
  vehicles = ['Vehicle 1', 'Vehicle 2', 'Vehicle 3', 'Vehicle 4', 'Vehicle 5'];
```

or

```
  vehicles: ['Vehicle 1', 'Vehicle 2', 'Vehicle 3', 'Vehicle 4', 'Vehicle 5'];
```

even

```
  vehicles = <String[]>['Vehicle 1', 'Vehicle 2', 'Vehicle 3', 'Vehicle 4', 'Vehicle 5'];
```

but in all of the cases when I use ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles">
    <div class="row" #row>
        <mat-card>{{vehicle}}</mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get the error

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

when I print console.log(this.vehicles) I get the response as expected:

> ["Vehicle 1", "Vehicle 2", "Vehicle 3", "Vehicle 4", "Vehicle 5"]

**how do I return the array as array Iterable and not object '[object Object]'?**

Comment: try declaring the array like this: `var vehicles = [];` and leave the rest as it is..

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: When I type {{vehicles}} in HTML I am getting '[object Object]' printed out on the page.

Comment: Your code looks absolutely fine. Try declaring `vehicle` as public..

Comment: public doesn't change anything either. I'll look into the rest of the code maybe include if anything might be related to this.

Comment: How about `ng-repeat`? Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I changed the name of object from vehicles to myObject and It worked. I looked into the html code and In a non-related place I found this code.

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="vehicle" name="vehicle" (selectionChange)="languageSelect()" #vehicles="ngModel">
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

#vehicles="ngModel" was screwing the ngFor before. I didn't realize I had the #vehicles later in the code or it would have any relation to my ngFor before. I think I accidantely left it from earlier code.

I also changed #vehicles to #myobjects seeing if the error would appear again. And yes it did. so the problem was definately in naming or repeating code.

Answer (score 0):

> You current code looks absolutely fine. It require some change in html, instead of printing `vehicles`, print `vehicle`.

```
<div *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles">
    <div class="row" #row>
        <mat-card>{{vehicle}}</mat-card> <!-- vehicles is changed to vechicle -->
    </div>
</div>
```

If are encountered with same error again, then you are getting this error from other code.

> Follow the steps to debug the issue

### Case 1

Remove the entire *ngFor segment and check if you are getting the error ?

```
<div></div>
```

### Case 2

Check if the following code is throwing the error

```
<div *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles">
    {{vehicle}}
</div>
```

### Case 3

Check if the following code is throwing the error

```
<div *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles">
    div class="row" #row>
        {{vehicle}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my bad. I did change that in code. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any other `*ngFor` ?

Comment: I had mentioned the steps to debug your issue, just let me know what is the behavior for different case.

Comment: I checked all of them only step one didn't give the error. I figured the problem was in something else than this. I posted the solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace {{vehicles}} with {{vehicle}} in the mat-card tag.